# Heroku: performance of Mongodb vs. Postgres

Tags: performance, postgresql, mongodb, heroku, amazon-ec2

I'm creating a python pyramid app on Heroku, and I was wondering if anyone can give me some insight on how the performance will compare between MongoDB (via Heroku's MongoHQ add on -> https://addons.heroku.com/mongohq) and the Heroku's built-in Postgres? It seems to me that MongoDB will be at a huge disadvantage here because its hosted on EC2 rather than locally, so any call to it will have to be on Amazon's remote servers.

But perhaps I'm wrong here. Can someone tell me whether my analysis is off or not?

Comment: Use  what you know best, performance is not an issue with small ammounts of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku is entirely hosted on Amazon EC2.

MongoDB will probably be faster than Postgres if you're just doing key/value stuff (like a typical blog), but Postgres will let you do more complex queries and has better reliability.